# Error Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::save does not exist. in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, postgresql

I want to change the status at $ result, to get the data at $ result I use query builder, but there is an error like  that

```
$results = ClientVendor::where('client_id','=', $request->client_id)
                                 ->where('vendor_id','=',$request->vendor_id)
        ->get();
        $results->status = $request->status;
        $results->save();
        return response()->json($results);
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cant do this because you call whole collection where is many elements. Call just single record, then you can update it.

When you use `get()` you call collection
When you use `first()` or `find($id)` then you get single record that you can update.

Look at example:

```
$results = ClientVendor::where('client_id', $request->client_id)
                        ->where('vendor_id',$request->vendor_id)
                        ->first(); // this point is the most important to change
$results->status = $request->status;
$results->save();
return response()->json($results);;
```

Good luck!

Comment: your response worked for me pal thanks. My issue was that at the point of fetching it was returning a list instead of just returning a single object

Answer (score 5):

You can try this one too.

```
 $results = ClientVendor::where('client_id','=', $request->client_id)
                             ->where('vendor_id','=',$request->vendor_id)
                             ->update([
                                     'status' => $request->status
                               ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$results = ClientVendor::where('client_id', $request->client_id)
                                 ->where('vendor_id',$request->vendor_id)
        ->first();
        $results->status = $request->status;
        $results->save();
        return response()->json($results);
```

Answer (score 2):

Many have suggested using `first()` instead of `get()`. I think `fistOrFail()` would be a better option to handle `null` results.

Otherwise, in cases where the result is null, you'd get `Call to a member function save() on null` error.

Eg:

**ClientVendor does not have a record with either client_id or vendor_id matching `$request->client_id` or `$request->client_id` respectively.**

```
$result = ClientVendor::where('client_id', $request->client_id)
                         ->where('vendor_id',$request->vendor_id)
                         ->first(); 
$result->status = $request->status; //produces error Creating default object from empty value
$result->save(); //produces error "Call to a member function save() on null" because $result will be empty
```

The above code produces 2 exceptions: 1. "Creating default object from empty value" on lines `$result->sataus = ..` and 2."Call to a member function save() on null" on line `$result->save` because *`$result` will be empty*.

To fix that, you would call `firstOrFail()` like so.

```
$result = ClientVendor::where('client_id', $request->client_id)
                             ->where('vendor_id',$request->vendor_id)
                             ->firstOrFail();
$result->status = $request->status; 
$result->save();
```

This fix, `firstOrFail`, when there are no results would produce a 404, a handled error, and the subsequent lines would not be executed.

For situations where you query using `find($id)`, it is better to use `findOrFail($id)`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your needs, if you want to :

1. **Get and update one record**, you should use `first()` or `firstOrFail()` instead of `get()`.  Should be look like this :

```
$results = ClientVendor::where('client_id', $request->client_id)
                         ->where('vendor_id',$request->vendor_id)
                         ->first();
$results->status = $request->status;
$results->save();
return response()->json($results);
```

2. **Get and update multiple records**, yes you can use `get()`, but you should do `foreach` and then update the single record one by one. just like this :

```
$results = ClientVendor::where('client_id', $request->client_id)
                         ->where('vendor_id',$request->vendor_id)
                         ->get();
foreach($results as $result){
    $result->status = $request->status;
    $result->save();
}
return response()->json($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update one item use find with it's primary key & then update.Or without primary key then use where & first.then update as like this Just Use

```
$results = ClientVendor::where('client_id', $request->client_id)
                        ->where('vendor_id',$request->vendor_id)
                        ->first();

$results->update([
        'status'=>$request->status
]);
return response()->json($results);
```